# Constraint Programming: Scheduling speakers in shortest time

Tags: scheduling, or-tools, constraint-programming, minizinc

I'm trying to adapt an already solved constraint programming problem by [Hakan Kjellerstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195636/hakank) (@hakankless) and could do with some help please.

***Original solved problem:*** There are 6 public speakers and 6 rooms. Each speaker should be assigned to a room, with no room left empty and each speaker in one room only.

Solutions here: [Google OR-Tools](https://github.com/hakank/hakank/blob/master/google_or_tools/scheduling_speakers.cs) & [MiniZinc](https://github.com/hakank/hakank/blob/master/minizinc/scheduling_speakers.mzn)

***Help with this adaptation:*** There are 3 public speakers and 6 time slots (i.e. one room). Each speaker should be assigned to one time slot, with the aim to minimize the duration from the starting slot (assumed to be starting from Slot 1, or if all busy, starting from the next available slot).

```
+---+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+---+------+------+------+
| 1 |      | Busy |      |
| 2 | Busy | Busy | Busy |
| 3 | Busy | Busy |      |
| 4 |      |      |      |
| 5 |      |      | Busy |
| 6 | Busy | Busy |      |
+---+------+------+------+
```

The solution would be (A,1), (C,3), (B,4). If we started with (C,1) then it would finish with (A,5) or (B,5). Since 4 < 5, the first solution is correct. **How can I solve this?**

Visual solution:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|   |    A     |    B     |    C     |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| 1 | SELECTED | Busy     |          |
| 2 | Busy     | Busy     | Busy     |
| 3 | Busy     | Busy     | SELECTED |
| 4 |          | SELECTED |          |
| 5 |          |          | Busy     |
| 6 | Busy     | Busy     |          |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your array dimensions mixed up.  It helps if you give your variables more meaningful names to make it more obvious what ranges over what.

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 3; % number of speakers
int: s = 6; % number of slots
array[1..n] of set of 1..s: available; % the available slots
array[1..n] of var 1..s: speaks_at; % the allotted speaker slot

solve :: int_search(speaks_at, first_fail, indomain_min, complete)
         minimize max(speaks_at);

constraint
   all_different(speaks_at)
   /\
   forall(i in 1..n) (
      speaks_at[i] in available[i]
   )
;

% at which slot is each speaker available to speak
available = [
    {1,4,5},  
    {4,5},  
    {1,3,4,6}  
];

output
[
    show(speaks_at)
];
```

This gives the expected answer:

```
% Starting search
Found a solution with cost 4
speaks_at = array1d(1..3, [1,4,3]);
% Minimum objective value = 4
% Total time 0.016s cpu (0.000 setup + 0.000 search)
----------
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought of this overnight too and came in this morning to try it, only to find you'd already posted this solution.

Comment: How would/could you adapt this solution if 'Speaker B' should speak for 2 consecutive slots?

Comment: At this point you will have to change model.  You could use a matrix of 0/1 variables with one variable per slot and speaker.  But closer to what you already have is a model where you consider each talk as a job with a start time variable and a duration.  You have to replace the alldifferent with a cumulative constraint, and you could also model the availability constraints as non-overlaps between unavailability and job, with one cumulative per speaker.

Comment: I've managed to adapt the code, however can't help but think it can be made more efficient. Can you help please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747059/optimizing-working-scheduling-minizinc-code-constraint-programming

Answer (score 3):

This is turning your *satisfaction* problem into an *optimisation* problem. That is, it is not enough to find *a* solution anymore, you want the *optimal* one. So for the MiniZinc model, you would need to change

```
solve :: int_search(x, first_fail, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;
```

to something like

```
solve :: int_search(x, first_fail, indomain_min, complete) minimize max(x);
```

to minimize the largest allocated time.

Comment: Lars, thanks that makes a lot of sense. However I can't seem to work out how to make MiniZinc or OR-Tools process a non-square matrix like the example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by non-square matrix -- the MiniZinc model has just a list of lists?

Comment: One of the available slot arrays is empty, i.e. there's no solution.

Comment: In my example in the OP, there is no availability in slot 2. I'm expecting to see a solution of (A,1), (C,3), (B,4).

Comment: No, this is not how constraint programming works. If domain of one of the variables is empty (no availability in your case), the problem has no solution. All the constraints must be satisfied.

Comment: I understand, thanks. How would you suggest I approach this problem?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. In this particular case you could just drop the no-availability variable. In general, you're looking at a [soft constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(mathematics)#Hard_and_soft_constraints) or [MaxSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) problem. For either you'll need a different modelling language/solver though.